# mysql query to pull results based on 3 advanced criteria and echo in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with a mysql query for php...

I have a table called 'table' with the following structure:

```
ID  EMAIL   GLOBAL_ID   VENDOR_ID   REVENUE USER
1   email1@email.com    123 7822    5   Bill
2   email1@email.com    123 90786   5   Paul
3   email1@email.com    123 17622   5   Mary
4   email2@email.com    124 1908    2   Eric
5   email3@email.com    125 189782  6   Jon
6   email3@email.com    125 11123   6   Paul
7   email4@email.com    126 11862   5   Dick
8   email4@email.com    126 271 5   Sue
9   email4@email.com    126 289871  5   George
10  email4@email.com    126 2211    5   Jack
11  email5@email.com    127 17771   10  Mary
12  email6@email.com    128 20891   5   Bill
13  email6@email.com    128 298981  5   Gary
```

I need a query to pull records where EMAIL and GLOBAL_ID together are unique (ie never include the same EMAIL/GLOBAL_ID combination twice) AND don't include if there are 3 or greater records that have the same EMAIL and GLOBAL_ID combination, AND i don't want to pull any records where USER = Jon.  So, from the data above and using php to echo, the following results should be displayed:

```
EMAIL   GLOBAL_ID
email2@email.com    124
email5@email.com    127
email6@email.com    128
```

*note i only need to echo out EMAIL and GLOBAL_ID

Any help with a query to echo this out in php to accomplish this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   EMAIL,GLOBAL_ID
FROM `table`
WHERE USER<>'Jon'
GROUP BY CONCAT(EMAIL,'@@',GLOBAL_ID)
HAVING COUNT(*)<3
```

Comment: you will get 6   email3@email.com    125 11123   6   Paul, no ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Why? I group by ... AH I forgot the DISTINCT, fixed my post, thanks

Comment: thank you.  i have tried this and the query keeps processing but nothing is happening.  My table is large (abt 40k records).  Is there a way you can think of that would speed up the query?

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE SQL table` to help us with the perofrmance aspects